# Why unloaded class is still accessible in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I loaded a class dynamically with `[NSBundle load]`. And unloaded it dynamically with `[NSBundle unload]`. Anyway it looks the class is still alive after unloading.

My code is:

```
// In separated bundle.
@implementation EEExampleBundle
+ (void)test
{
    NSLog(@"TTTTT");
}
@end




// In executable file.
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {
        id  EEExampleBundle         =   nil;

        @autoreleasepool 
        {   
            NSString*   path            =   [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EEExampleBundle.framework"];
            NSBundle*   sampleBundle    =   [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

            [sampleBundle load];


            EEExampleBundle     =   (id)[sampleBundle classNamed:@"EEExampleBundle"];

            [EEExampleBundle test];

            BOOL    r   =   [sampleBundle unload];
            NSLog(@"unload result = %d", r);
        }
        [EEExampleBundle test];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2011-09-25 01:08:52.713 driver[2248:707] TTTTT
2011-09-25 01:08:52.714 driver[2248:707] unload result = 1
2011-09-25 01:08:52.716 driver[2248:707] TTTTT
```

Why the class code is still working? Is this normal? Or should I do any extra step to unload the code completely?

P.S
I'm not using *ARC*. I turned it off explicitly.

Comment: Why are you using `retainCount`? I'm surprised that, as you are using ARC, LLVM is not flagging this up as an error?

Comment: @Abizern You're right. the `-retainCount` looks deprecated. So I've updated code :) Anyway I haven't used *ARC*. I turned off it explicitly (`CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO`) because it makes `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` calling code from bundle loaded dynamically.

Comment: But you are using `@autoreleasepool` which has a specific meaning.

Comment: @Abizern According to Apple's documentation, the `@autorelease` keyword is compatible with non-ARC mode.

Comment: autorelease pool will not immediately release an object. if you had done non ARC code you would remember the use of autoRelease message. (think how can you have a factory method if autoRelease would immediately release an object ? :) )

Comment: @nsuinteger As far as I remember, all the methods I used in the example code all return an autoreleased (or singleton) object by Cocoa naming convention defined by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

(more of a comment than an answer, nevertheless:) That's due to the inner @autoreleasepool block, no? You won't be able to create a new instance from your bundle, but you do keep the ones already created alive (else, that'd generate fancy bugs).